# Will we have a CLI version of typescript provided by .NET Framework?

Tags: typescript

This is a question much more philosophical than technical, so what do you think? There is a way of we get a typescript language to use on CLI, like VB.NET and C#?

Comment: Somebody sooner or later will come up with the idea that you can cross-compile it to C# instead of Javascript.  And miss the point.

Answer (score 3):

The role of traditional C# / VB console apps is already fulfilled by node.js. Nothing TypeScript-specific is needed.